# Python Unit Testing Mock input registering wrong input

Tags: python, unit-testing, if-statement, mocking, nested

So I am new to unit testing and I am trying to figure out why the mock input is reading as `'yes'` I'm not sure why when I mock the input as `'no'` 
Here is my run code.

```
def main():

    newGame = input("")

    if newGame == "yes" or "y":
        print("TEST1")
    elif newGame == "no" or "n":
        print("TEST2")
    else:
        print("TEST3")
```

Nothing to crazy, pretty straight forward. Here is my test code.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import io
import sys

from RunFile import main

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('builtins.input', return_value="no")
  def test_output(self,m):
      saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          main()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          self.assertEqual("TEST2",output)
      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout


if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Also, here is the trace back.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_output (__main__.GetInputTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1087, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "C:/Users/jsalce/Documents/Testsuites/IfStatements/Testsuite.py", line 18, in test_output
    self.assertEqual("TEST",output)
AssertionError: 'TEST2' != 'TEST1'
- TEST2
+ TEST1
?     +
```

Like I mentioned before I set the input to "no" I don't know whats going on.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your patch is actually working fine; you've just made a mistake with your if statements. You really want this:

```
def main():

    newGame = input("")

    if newGame == "yes" or newGame == "y":
        print("TEST1")
    elif newGame == "no" or newGame == "n":
        print("TEST2")
    else:
        print("TEST3")
```

Which can more succinctly be written as:

```
def main():
    newGame = input("")

    if newGame in ["yes", "y"]:
        print("TEST1")
    elif newGame in ["no", "n"]:
        print("TEST2")
    else:
        print("TEST3")
```

Your current if statement is being evaluated as `if (newGame == "yes") or "y":`. Since `bool("y")` is `True`, that if statement will always evaulate to `True`, which is why `"TEST1"` is getting printed.